# Remove 91 from mobile_number_column in R

Tags: r

Eg: Mobile_Number column contains

```
read.table(header=T,text=' Mobile_Number_Column

    919177289917
    917728991746
    917728991748
    919126380348

')
```

Now I want to remove 91 from `Mobile_Number_Column`

Expected Result:

```
Mobile_Number_Column

    9177289917
    7728991746
    7728991748
    9126380348
```

Comment: `gsub("\\s91"," ","Mobile_Number_Column 919177289917 917728991746 917728991748 919126380348")`

Comment: `df$Mobile_Number_Column <- gsub('^91', '', df$Mobile_Number_Column)`

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished with a regular expression. Since you're reading in the numbers as part of a data.frame, you can leverage the `^` start of string matcher plus the literal numbers of 91 in a `sub` call. No point in `gsub` since you only want to match once.

```
df =  read.table(header=T,text=' Mobile_Number_Column

    919177289917
    917728991746
    917728991748
    919126380348

') 

df$Mobile_Number_Column = sub("^91","",as.character(df$Mobile_Number_Column))
df 
#>   Mobile_Number_Column
#> 1           9177289917
#> 2           7728991746
#> 3           7728991748
#> 4           9126380348
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses the `stringr` and `dplyr` packages:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(numbers = c(
    919177289917,
    917728991746,
    917728991748,
    919126380348)
    )

data_2 <- data %>%
  mutate(numbers = str_sub(numbers, start = 3L, end = -1L))
```